# Connect Metamask with a native mobile app built with Flutter

Tags: flutter, native, metamask

I want to connect the app to Metamask to get the user account and signature from the user to confirm the transaction. But the problem is that when I enter Metamask from the app, I am not asked any questions to confirm the connection and nothing happens inside Metamask, it is like only the Metamask app is opened and when I back up and return to the app, the null account is returned.

```
_walletConnect() async {
    final connector = WalletConnect(
      bridge: 'https://bridge.walletconnect.org',
      clientMeta: const PeerMeta(
        name: 'WalletConnect',
        description: 'WalletConnect Developer App',
        url: 'https://walletconnect.org',
        icons: [
          'https://gblobscdn.gitbook.com/spaces%2F-LJJeCjcLrr53DcT1Ml7%2Favatar.png?alt=media'
        ],
      ),
    );
    // Subscribe to events
    connector.on('connect', (session) => print(session));
    connector.on('session_update', (payload) => print(payload));
    connector.on('disconnect', (session) => print(session));

    // Create a new session
    if (!connector.connected) {
      session = await connector.createSession(
          chainId: 97,
          onDisplayUri: (uri) async => {print(uri), await launch(uri)});
    }

    setState(() {
      account = session.accounts[0];
      print(account);
    });

    if (account != null) {
      final client = Web3Client(rpc, Client());
      EthereumWalletConnectProvider provider =
          EthereumWalletConnectProvider(connector);
      credentials = WalletConnectEthereumCredentials(provider: provider);
      yourContract = ethUtils.getDeployedContract(myAddress, client);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It sometimes happened to me as well.
I had just closed the MetaMask app and clicked on the button (Which triggered this function) and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I made a library for this, web3_connect, uses the same code and it gets the address back just fine for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing a reference link to the library & an example of how it works.

Comment: could you share with me that please :D